# perl file upload can't init filehandle

Tags: perl

I tried to use this very simple script for uploading a file to my server. For some reason it is not working. I get the following message in my apache error log:

---

```
Use of uninitialized value in <HANDLE> at /opt/www/demo1/upload/image_upload_2.pl line 15.
readline() on unopened filehandle at /opt/www/demo1/upload/image_upload_2.pl line 15.
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use CGI;  

 $upload_dir = "/opt/www/demo1/upload/data"; 
 $query = new CGI; 
 $filename = $query->param("photo"); 
 $filename =~ s/.*[\/\\](.*)/$1/; 
 $upload_filehandle = $query->upload("photo"); 

 open UPLOADFILE, ">$upload_dir/$filename"; 
 binmode UPLOADFILE; 

 while ( <$upload_filehandle> ) 
 { 
   print UPLOADFILE; 
 } 

 close UPLOADFILE;

 1
```

Any ideas what is wrong there?
Thanks
mx

Comment: Does the file really exist? Does your script have the correct permissions to access it?

Comment: What permissions are neccesary? It has 777 - and if I printout something it is working. The file I want write is also 777 but it crashes bevore, it doesn't get the handle from the CGI object.

In the form that calls the script I have the following input field:
<input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" size="20" />

This is correct, isn't it?

Comment: What is the `enctype` for the `form` tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

File upload forms need to specify `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. See [W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3).

In addition, note the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use CGI;

my $upload_dir = "/opt/www/demo1/upload/data"; 
my $query = CGI->new; # avoid indirect object notation

my $filename = $query->param("photo"); 
$filename =~ s/.*[\/\\](.*)/$1/; # this validation looks suspect

my $target = "$upload_dir/$filename";

# since you are reading binary data, use read to
# read chunks of a specific size

my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload("photo"); 
if ( defined $upload_filehandle ) {
    my $io_handle = $upload_filehandle->handle;
    # use lexical filehandles, 3-arg form of open
    # check for errors after open
    open my $uploadfile, '>', $target
        or die "Cannot open '$target': $!";
    binmode $uploadfile;

    my $buffer;        
    while (my $bytesread = $io_handle->read($buffer,1024)) {
        print $uploadfile $buffer
            or die "Error writing to '$target': $!";
    }
    close $uploadfile
        or die "Error closing '$target': $!";
}
```

See [CGI documentation](http://search.cpan.org/CGI#PROCESSING_A_FILE_UPLOAD_FIELD).

Comment: File upload forms need to specify enctype="multipart/form-data".

That was the trick! Thanks!! (Also fot the other hints)

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading a text file then below should be set in `<head>` of html file:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Otherwise the `$file_name = $query->param("file_name")` is defined in scalar context (`print $file_name`) and undef in file context ( `<$file_name>` ).